# Illegal cyclic reference involving class

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala, and am stuck with an error involving generics. I've defined a trait as

```
trait myTrait[
  A, B,
  Self[X, Y] <: myTrait[X, Y, Self]] { 
 protected def self: Self[A, B] 
}
```

and my class as

```
class myClass[B] extends myTrait[Int, B, myClass]{ 
  override protected def self:myClass[B] = this 
}
```

This gives me a compile error "illegal cyclic reference involving class myClass". The error goes away if I declare myClass as

```
class myClass[A, B] extends myTrait[A, B, myClass]{ 
  override protected def self:myClass[A, B] = this 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the error I get in 2.11.7:

```
myClass takes one type parameter, expected: two
```

Which makes sense: `myClass` is used as the `Self` argument of `MyTrait`, which requires two type parameters.